# .sort() acting weird with multiple arrays of text and numbers

Tags: arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, concatenation

I have been messing around with the .sort() and .concat() functions trying to combine multiple arrays of numbers and text into one and chronologically order it. It seems to work fine if only numbers are input into the array but as soon as there is text it seems to place it randomly, in this case between 6 and 7. Also, if I remove the number 3 from the array, the number 4 ends up out of order after the text, both being between 9 and 10. I have no idea why it is doing this if anyone could help.

With only numbers:

```
var multiArray = [[2, 8, 1, 7, 9], [6, 3, 5, 4, 10]];

// returns 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
document.write(multiArray[0]
           .concat(multiArray[1])
           .sort() 
           +"<br/>");

 // returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
document.write(multiArray[0]
               .concat(multiArray[1])
               .sort((a,b)=>a-b) 
               +"<br/>");
```

and with text

```
var multiArray = [[2, 8, 1, 7, 9], [6, 3, 5, "text", 4, 10]];

// returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,text,7,8,9,10
document.write(multiArray[0]
               .concat(multiArray[1])
               .sort((a,b)=>a-b) 
               +"<br/>");
```

and without 3

```
var multiArray = [[2, 8, 1, 7, 9], [6, 5, "text", 4, 10]];

// returns 1,2,5,6,7,8,9,text,4,10
document.write(multiArray[0]
               .concat(multiArray[1])
               .sort((a,b)=>a-b) 
               +"<br/>");
```

Comment: what do you expect `a - b` to do with strings ?

Comment: `.sort()` does not do a numerical sort.  You have to pass it a custom sort callback to do a numerical sort.  That explains your first result.

Comment: Your second and third results are from a mixture of numbers and text, but you use a comparison function that isn't smart about numbers and text.  Garbage in, garbage out.  Your a-b is going to end up trying to do type coercion when you give it a string and a number which will just give you a nonsense result.  If you're going to mix text and numbers, you need a comparison function that detects a comparison between mixed types and implements exactly how you want the comparison algorithm to work in that case.

Comment: FYI, the `.concat()` in this question has nothing to do with anything.  The question is the same if you just start with a flat array and skip the `.concat()` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, combine all arrays in a single array

```
var multiArray = [[2, 8, 1, 'foo', 7, '1', 9], [6, 5, 'text', 4, 'bar', 10]];
var flattenArray = [].concat(...multiArray);        // [ 2, 8, 1, 'foo', 7, '1', 9, 6, 5, 'text', 4, 'bar', 10 ]
```

then sort separately numbers and strings

```
const sortedNumbers = flattenArray
    .filter(n => typeof n === 'number')
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);

const sortedStrings = flattenArray
    .filter(n => typeof n === 'string')
    .sort();
```

finally, concat both

```
const sorted = sortedNumbers.concat(sortedStrings);     // [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, '1', 'bar', 'foo', 'text' ]
```

I assume you want strings after your numbers. Otherwise, simply invert the concatenation:

```
const sorted = sortedStrings.concat(sortedNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks that makes so much sense. I was a little bit confused on how .sort((a, b) => a - b) worked but now I get it. I must have been assuming it would convert the text into unicode or binary and sort it that way or something.